# if A1 is blank enter data otherwise enter in A2 cell

Tags: excel

In excel, I need formula like I will enter data in Sheet 1 in B1 cell, it has to enter those data in Sheet 2 with a condition like if  A1 is blank enter data otherwise enter in  A2 cell. Please anyone tell me if any formula is available for this.

Comment: What's your effort thus far?

Answer (score 0):

In Sheet2 :

```
B1     =IF(Sheet1!A1="","",Sheet1!B1)
A2     =IF(Sheet1!A1<>"","",Sheet1!B1)
```

Does it work for you?

Comment: No, it is not working. I don't want to  override data in sheet 2 A1 cell. I will always enter data in sheet1 B1 cell, automatically it has to enter those data in sheet2 one after one row. Example: First time I will enter Ram in sheet1 B1, it has to store Ram in sheet 2 A1 automatically, if I enter again Khan in Sheet 1 B1 cell, automatically it has to store Khan in sheet 2 A2 cell.

Comment: " I don't want to override data in sheet 2 A1 cell." <-- only sheet 2 A2 &  sheet 2 B1 cell are affected.  nothing is done/entered in sheet 2 A1  (: